# Maven finds artifact in local repo but fails to compile

Tags: java, android, maven, dependencies, gradle

I recently asked this question about a maven project that I inherited from another developer:  [Maven finds artifact but cannot compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598191/maven-finds-artifact-but-cannot-compile/18601903?noredirect=1#18601903)

As per the instructions in the accepted answer I cloned the library from Github and built it with a mvn install.  I was able to get past the error that I was stuck on when I asked that question, but once again I am stuck with a strange issue.  I thought it was the same so I made sure the library was installed in the local repo and everything was working, Yet when I try to compile my application I get an error that a specific class cannot be found.

```
error: cannot find symbol class ColorPicker
```

The library, HoloColorPicker, is in my .m2 repo and maven says nothing about missing dependencies.  It just will not find that specific class.  I am not sure where to even begin fixing this issue.  A pointer towards the right direction would be great.  Thanks.

Update:

When I run mvn dependency:tree I see this warning about the ColorPicker pom.xml :

```
Invalid POM for com.larswerkman:colorpicker:apklib:7, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available
```

Comment: My bet is that the `systemPath` dependency in the colorpicker POM is causing you trouble. You should in general not depend on projects that have `systemPath` dependencies. But if you do, could you make sure it's there?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen I was just about to post saying that the systemPath dependency was what was causing the problem and removing it fixed my issue.  I would like to accept your comment as an answer if you want to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that the `systemPath` dependency in the colorpicker POM is causing you trouble. You should in general not depend on projects that have `systemPath` dependencies. But if you do, could you make sure it's there?